# F# Library in Silverlight Application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, f#

I have an F# library in the same solution as a Silverlight (C#) project that I'd like to use the library in. When I try to add a reference to the library project, it says I can only add Silverlight references. How can I make this F# library compatible with my Silverlight project?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This looks like a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237044/how-does-silverlight-determine-an-assembly-is-silverlight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start with an 'F# Silverlight Library' rather than 'F# library' project template.

Answer (score 2):

The F# compiler automatically generates assembly for some non-standard runtime (such as Silverlight or Compact Framework) if you reference the appropriate (non-standard) version of the `mscorlib.dll` and `FSharp.Core.dll` assemblies in your F# project. The Silverlight version of the assemblies can be found here (on my machine):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v3.0\mscorlib.dll
>   C:\Programs\Development\FSharp-1.9.9.9\Silverlight\2.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll

This is a more user-friendly replacement for the `--noframework` and `--cli-root` parameters mentioned in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237044/how-does-silverlight-determine-an-assembly-is-silverlight) referenced by Pretzel.

Comment: April, 2013 --- Hi Tomas. Been looking for latest Fsharp Silverlight recommendations, information ...